# iOS 5: How can I preserve newline while retrieving values from mysql via PHP in UITextView and UIWebView

Tags: mysql, ios, uiwebview, uitextview

I am retrieving values from mysql database (using PHP) and displaying it in UITextView and some portion in UIWebView. The Values that I had stored in database were in TEXT but when I display it in UITextView the data which I want to display in points gets displayed as a paragraph. How can I make a newline since the data that I receive is already in a NSString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITextView puts a new line on `\n`, UIWebView shows html and if you have just a plain text with some links or something, you may add a `<br />` for a new line.
So in order to preserve line breaks for UITextView you need `\n` and for UIWebView valid line-breaking-HTML (for example `<br />`).

Not sure why you're getting a paragraph, maybe you over-escape or something in you php routines?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I was able to do it, using the following code :

```
NSString *myNewLineStr = @"<br />";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:myNewLineStr];
```